# Find and remove over SSH?

Tags: security, ssh, removeall

My web server got hacked (Despite the security team telling me nothing was compromised) and an uncountable number of files have an extra line of PHP code generating a link to some Vietnamese website.

Given there are tens of thousands of files across my server, is there a way I can go in with SSH and remove that line of code from every file it's found in?

Please be specific in your answer, I have only used SSH a few times for some very basic tasks and don't want to end up deleting a bunch of my files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a few lines of shell script would do it. I hesitate to give it to you, though, as if something goes wrong I'll get blamed for messing up your web server. That said, the solution could be as simple as this:

```
for i in `find /where/ever -name '*.php'`; do
    mv $i $i.bak
    grep -v "http://vietnamese.web.site" $i.bak >> $i
done
```

This finds all the `*php` files under `/where/ever`, and removes any lines that have `http://vietnamese.web.site` in them. It makes a `*.bak` copy of every file. After you run this and all seems good, you could delete the backups with

```
find . -name '*.php.bak' -exec rm \{\} \;
```

Your next task would be to find a new provider, as not only did they get hacked, but they apparently don't keep backups. Good luck.

Comment: Ernest,
There are php and HTML files that are affected, if I just use * would it check every file?

Of course, the actual code is a piece of PHP so it's not an actual link until it's parsed. I can put the <?php code> in place of the URL?

I will ask my host if they can do this for me to ensure it's done properly. If not, I will give it a go, I'm not going to try and do it manually.

Comment: All of these commands are very flexible. If you want the `find` to find all `*.htm` as well as all `*.php` files, then you could use predicates like `find /where/ever -name '*.php' -or -name '*.htm'`. The URL is just an example, use whatever unique string you can come up with to identify the  lines you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

First create a regex, that matches the bad code (and only the bad code), then run

```
find /path/to/webroot -name \*.php -exec echo sed -i -e 's/your-regex-here//' {} \;
```

If everything looks right, remove the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

I do it following way.  E.g. to delete files matching particular name  or extension.

rm -rf * cron.php. *

rm -rf * match_string *

where *match_string* will be any string. Make sure there will be no space between * and string name.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -f cron.php.*
```

Delete all file in this folder called **cron.php.[whereveryouwant]**